# Access tuple element in C++11 via compile time variable in function

Tags: c++, c++11, stdtuple

The following minimal example compiles with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall tuple.cpp -o tuple`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<int i>
char get_elem_i(std::tuple<char, char> t)
{
    return std::get<i>(t);
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<char, char> t('H','i');
    char c = get_elem_i<0>(t);
    std::cout << "The char is: " << c << std::endl;
}
```

Now, I do not want to use a template which specifies the index (the exact reason why: I have templates that are deduced automatically, and I do not want to need to specify them all). So my first try was:

```
char get_elem_i(int i, std::tuple<char, char> t)
{
    return std::get<i>(t);
}
```

I understand that this can not compile. Is there any way to assure the compiler that `i` will be known at compile time? Maybe something like this?

```
char get_elem_i(compile_time_known int i, std::tuple<char, char> t)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `std::array` instead of a `std::tuple`. In the example given, the members of the tuple all have the same type.

So, we could do:

```
char get_elem_i(int i, std::array<char, 2> t)
{
    return t[i];
}
```

---

Here's a slight variant on the example you gave to show why it's not directly possible in the general case:

```
???? get_elem_i(int i, std::tuple<char, struct foo, class bar> t) {
    return std::get<i>(t);
}
```

What is the return type of that function? `char`? `struct foo`?

---

And you could always write a function like this:

```
char get_elem_i(int i, std::tuple<char, char> t) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0: return std::get<0>(t);
        case 1: return std::get<1>(t);
    }

    assert(false);
}
```

Comment: "What is the return type of that function?" I'd say that isn't actually the problem - you could use a `auto ... -> decltype(...)` kind of function declaration to fix that problem. The problem is that the `int i` parameter is being used as a template parameter in `std::get<i>`.

Comment: @TimothyShields: Sure, what's the result of the decltype? A variant? The __reason__ that `i` is a template argument is because the return type of `std::get` varies based on that input.

Comment: @TimothyShields: I also agree that my middle function doesn't compile. It's to explain that `i` needs to be a template parameter in the general case.

Comment: @sharth Thanks, the switch works! Is this the only/best solution? I  just ask because it is still 4 lines of code, and maybe not runtime-perfect. If there will be no solution to that in the next days, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @sharth What's also a problem: The switch relies on knowing the type of the std::tuple. So I can not use a template for the type of tuple.

Answer (score 1):

If you can know the value of `i` at compile time then you can getting around specifying specifying the explicit value of `i` by wrapping your logic for `i` in a`constexpr`.

For example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

constexpr int compile_time_known_i(int input) { return input / 3; }

template<int i>
char get_elem_i(std::tuple<char, char> t)
{
    return std::get<i>(t);
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<char, char> t('H','i');
    char c = get_elem_i<0>(t);
    char d = get_elem_i<compile_time_known_i(3)>(t);
    std::cout << "The char is: " << c << " " << d <<  std::endl;
}
```

Given your `i`'s can be known at compile time, this may help clean things up (although how much sense this makes depends on your use case).

If it's the syntax of passing a parameter you are after, you could achieve this with the preprocessor - with some optional `type_traits` safety.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#define get_elem_i_ct(i, t)                                                                \
    std::get<i>(t);                                                                        \
    static_assert(std::is_integral<decltype(i)>::value, #i " must be an integral type");   \
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(t), std::tuple<char, char>>::value, #t " must be a tuple");

int main()
{
    std::tuple<char, char> t('H','i');
    char c = get_elem_i_ct(0, t)
    char d = get_elem_i_ct(1, t)
    std::cout << "The char is: " << c << " " << d <<  std::endl;
}
```

Although this achieves the stated  syntactical requirement, I wouldn't recommend using this approach in anger - there's almost certainly a better solution to your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks, but this still needs a template parameter. Is it impossible to use none?

Comment: I would not like to use a macro. But this is interesting, thanks!